# XAML: Subtract a constant from markup-extension

Tags: xaml

In my XAML File there is the following Line:

```
<TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding ValueOutput}" 
TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderBrush="#FF000000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   
VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" x:Name="textBox"  
Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" 
FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" />
```

I want to change the Width-Attribute so there's allways subtracted one constant pixel from the defined Width.
It should be something like

```
Width="{TemplateBinding Width}-1"
```

I know XAML just for a few days and i cant find anything on the internet to solve this problem so far. Is it just a syntax-problem or is it impossible to do this?

Thank you for your answers!

Sven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just do this in XAML. You'll need some code-behind for this. You'll have to use Converter and ConvertParameter in your binding code in XAML. Here's a little more about the topic:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx

I'm sure you'll be able to find more if you search for "XAML databinding converter"